# ARC welder camera access with OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, google-chrome-arc

Does anyone know how to use OpenCV to get camera frames on ARC welder ? I'm using only native code here. OpenCV was the easiest way to get frames on Android.
I'm having troubles with it on ARC. It seems to be looking for packages that don't exist :

```
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): CvCapture_Android::CvCapture_Android(0)
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Library name: libbitmapToolkit.so
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Library base address: 0xde0c0000
E/OpenCV::camera(  204): Could not read /proc/self/smaps
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Trying to find native camera in default OpenCV packages
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Trying package "org.opencv.lib_v24_armv7a" ("/data/data/org.opencv.lib_v24_armv7a/lib/")
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Package not found
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Trying package "org.opencv.engine" ("/data/data/org.opencv.engine/lib/")
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): Package not found
D/OpenCV::camera(  204): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib: folderPath=
E/OpenCV::camera(  204): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library
E/OpenCV::camera(  204): Native_camera returned opening error: 4
```

"libbitmapToolkit.so" is our dll asking opencv to open the camera device.

Thanks.